# using relationship table data to build query removing certain rows within the query based on variable

Tags: mysql, join, relationship

I may be going about this the wrong way as i could not find a question quite like this.

i have a product table

```
id - name - parent
---|------|--------
1  |p-A   |  0    -default
2  |p-A1  |  1    -default
3  |p-u1  |  0    -USER ADDED
```

i have a relationship table that couples userID with PID (BUT it also has an on/off field)

```
id - uid - pid - on(0=no, 1=yes)
---|-----|-----|----
1  | 0   | 1   | 1 - uid-0 for default association(ok?)
2  | 0   | 2   | 1
3  | 1   | 3   | 1 - USER ADDED association
4  | 1   | 2   | 0 - USER does not want this default product
```

so I can grab the defaults and the user added products with a query like this BUT obviously the AND clause does nothing because I already selected the row in the first WHERE clause.

```
SELECT prod.id, prod.name, prod.parent, rel.pid, rel.uid, rel.on 
FROM prod, rel 
WHERE rel.uid = 0 OR rel.uid = '$uid' 
AND rel.on <> 0
```

I can not seem to figure out how to omit the products that are turned off for the specific user in the query without going through a php function

NOTE: I know that i could create a user/product association for ever user to the defaults but i did not want to insert those 15 associations for every user. I also did not want to make a default products table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're missing a parenthesis. Without the parenthsis around the OR the query will return all records that match either of those conditions. You're also missing the join between prod and rel, so that will return extra records as well.

```
SELECT prod.id, prod.name, prod.parent, rel.pid, rel.uid 
FROM prod
    INNER JOIN rel ON prod.id = rel.id
WHERE (rel.uid = 0 OR rel.uid = '$uid')
AND rel.on <> 0
```

to simplify you could use an IN statement rather than an OR

```
SELECT prod.id, prod.name, prod.parent, rel.pid, rel.uid 
FROM prod
    INNER JOIN rel ON prod.id = rel.id
WHERE rel.uid IN (0,'$uid')
AND rel.on <> 0
```

Comment: oh, I like the IN rather than OR.. However it still grabs the default product as part of the uid=0 match.. How do i tell it to go back and remove that product if there is an entry where on=0 for that pid?

Comment: you're also missing a join between prod and rel. I've updated my answer.

Comment: it seems like we are getting closer.. This new statement removed the user added product from the list but did not remove the product designated by the user to be turned off

Comment: what happens if you use `AND rel.on = 1` ? I'm out of ideas other than that

Comment: changed the rel.id to rel.pid and rel.on <> 0 it shows all products for the user but does not omit the off product pid=2... changing rel.on <> 1 turns off all products but pid=2...